# DTO saving design with multiple tables

Tags: java, database, dto

I'm having a DTO design problem.
I have a DTO User that joins three database tables: Person, Student, Address. And also three individual DAOs: Person, Student, Address.

User pulls everything from three tables:

```
SELECT * 
from Person p LEFT JOIN Student s on p.Person_ID = s.Person_ID 
              LEFT JOIN Address a on p.Person_ID = a.Person_ID
```

What's the best way to do save?

If I only update LastName in Person table, when I do User.saveToDatabase(), how to determine if it only needs to call Person.save(), rather than call Person.save(), Student.save() and Address.save() everytime even though nothing needs to be updated in Student and Address?

Comment: I could not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: How does your User DTO looks like? All attributes of person, student, address just flat in that object? How do you call exactly the save method for a person in your DAO?

Comment: User contains all attributes of person, student, address. I use raw sql to do pull and save. person.save is just a insert/update query into Person table.